# Woocommerce custom attributes not created, wc_create_attribute still working?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

Is there something i am missing?
I try to create a new custom attribute for plugin purpose, but somehow it doesnt work.
The simple function is as follows:

```
$data = array(
    'name'   => 'programmas',
    'slug'    => 'elearning_programmas',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'order_by' => 'menu_order',
    'has_archives'  => 1
  );        
 wc_create_attribute( $data );
```

However, whatever i do, no new attribute is created in the list with attributes under the product attributes page, neither available on the individual product page.

Any ideas?